# Placing jQuery Validate plugin messages in new line

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate.

It's all working as it should but the messages are displaying one beside the other when there are more that one.

I need the messages to display in their own line.

```
$("#myform").validate({

errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
debug: false,
rules: {
name: "required",
email: {
required: true,
email: true,
},
password: {
required: true,
minlength: 8
},
},
messages: {
name: "Please enter your name.",
email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
password: "Please enter at least 8 password characters.",
}
});
```

> ```
> Current display: 
>
> Message1Message2Message3
>
> Wanted display: 
>
> Message1
> Message2
> Message3
> ```

How can I do this?

Comment: Simply use the `wrapper` option.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/TSKHX/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can add div's around the messages and style them properly.

```
name: "<div class='msgRow'>Please enter your name.</div>",
email: "<div class='msgRow'>Please enter a valid email address.</div>",
password: "<div class='msgRow'>Please enter at least 8 password characters.</div>",
```

Comment: **This answer is a hack** and it will give you invalid HTML where a `<div>` is inside a `<label>`.  Simply use the plugin's `wrapper` option.  See:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions and http://jsfiddle.net/TSKHX/

Comment: Oh i'm sorry for that. I've upped your answer.

Answer (score 15):

**The accepted answer is a hack**...

1) you will end up with the following [**invalid** HTML](http://validator.w3.org/).

```
<label><div>Your message</div></label>
```

2) you would be required to declare a custom message to over-ride every single default message.

---

The correct method is to use the plugin's built-in `wrapper` option, which ***changes*** the `label` into a `div` for each message automatically.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/TSKHX/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        wrapper: 'div',
        errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
        // your other rules & options
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple add `<br/>` tag in front of error messages:

```
messages: {"name": {required: "<br/>Error validation message"}}
```